# Broken references in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a large solution with many project. We have about six developers working on this solution using `VS2013` and it is source controlled by `TFS 2013`.

Periodically project references and file references to `DLLs` are broken. The little yellow sign with the black exclamation point shows next to the reference in the project references and when I look at the properties of the broken references, I noticed that the `path` was empty for the elements that are broken.
I could remove and re-add the references, but I have done this a few times before and it keeps breaking again.

I Googled around and found several people talking about similar issues, but in most cases I see, after removing and adding the references, everything is ok.
I my case, this keeps happening over and over.

Is there a known cause for this? I can keep re-fixing this, but it's just a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: Does the references broken issue happen on your client machine or on TFS machine? Have you added these DLLs into TFS?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - The DLLs are from other projects in the same solution. 
They are added as project references, not file references. The broken references aren't created in TFS (I don't think so at least), but I guess someone is checking them in, because we see the same issue in our build agents with clear workspace as well.

Comment: Will this issue happen when you have a local build (don't use TFS build)?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - Yes, this happens both locally and in the build agents.

Comment: As this issue happen on both locally and TFS build, the issue is not TFS related, but the solution itself.

Comment: You may need to check the history of the project first to see who check in the changes for the reference,

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - This is exactly what I ended up doing. Turns out that the project was referenced in a different solution and project references were switched with DLL references, with paths relative to the other solution. Strange that VS didn't show an error when it couldn't find the path to the DLLs and instead gave a build error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming ProjectFirst generates the DLLs for ProjectSecond, to narrow down the issue, you can first build the ProjectFirst and then build the ProjectSecond to see whether the behavior correct. If that works, you probably need to check your build order.

In **Solution Explorer**, select a project or select the solution. On the **Project** menu, choose **Project Build Order** to check the build order. 
On the **Dependencies** tab, select ProjectSecond from the **Project** drop-down menu. In the **Depends on** field, select the check box of ProjectFirst that must build before this project does.

Additionally, check ProjectSecond to see whether it by default to targeting .NET Client Profile. If it is, change it to regular .NET.

Comment: "Additionally, check ProjectSecond to see whether it by default to targeting .NET Client Profile. If it is, change it to regular .NET."  - Yep, that was it.  I was going nuts trying to remove and re-add the reference.  I never would've checked the target framework.

Answer (score 2):

We have a solution with hundreds of projects (> 400) and tens of thousands of source files and for some unknown reason a set of updates got applied to the machine right in the middle of a build, killing the build and closing Visual Studio.  When VS was reopened some projects did not load (even after close and re-open) so had to sort through > 400 projects and find those that did not load and **manually tell VS to reload the missing/not loaded projects**.  After that things seem back to normal.